# How to iterate through Socket.object and only return values that match?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When a new user connects, nothing happens yet. They first have to enter a first name or nickname. Upon submitting that form

```
    sock.on('new user', function(data) {...}
```

is called. In which I assign `sock.username = data;` and `sock.roomNumber = roomNo; roomNo` increases by 1 every time a room is full.

As for my question, how the heck can I iterate through the sock object and only return the sock objects of those where `sock.roomNumber` matches `roomNo`?

I hope I explained that right. This thing has been whooping my butt all day. Ay caramba!

Comment: There are multiple `sock` objects, one for each user. Whenever a user connects, a new sock object is created. If you want to iterate over them, you have to push them into an array. Also, `socket.io` supports rooms natively, so depending on what you're trying to do, you might be on the wrong track.

Comment: I am using rooms. At first I did push them into arrays at first. On connect I placed the sockets into an array called connections. After users entered their username, I pushed the usernames into an array called players. `Players.push(sock.username);` Problem was when I had to emit to the players in  a certain room. I didn't know how to access the sock object of the players having only a username to work with. So I changed to using rooms.

Comment: Just to be clear: players are in rooms already, and you want to emit an event, but only to the other players/sockets in the room, right? Since each player/socket knows their own room name, just use `socket.to(roomName).emit(whatever)`